# back button uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to make a custom back button to pop back to parent in nav controller. I understand I should've made the back button in parent controller itself

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem= backBarButton`

The button was just default button with custom text, but it worked. None of formatting or fonts showed up. 
So instead I made a custom leftBarButton in child VC:

```
UIButton *backBtn= [[UIButton alloc] init];
backBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
backBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CrimeFighter BB" size:20];
backBtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
backBtn.titleLabel.text = @"back";
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

Its working fine, but the button is not visible at all!

Answer (score 1):

New attempt:

[Doing an alloc & init on a UIButton isn't the right way to create a button in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996530/why-uibutton-does-not-require-to-alloc-and-init).

The way to programatically create a button is:

```
UIButton * backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Original attempt:

You need to give your custom back button a proper size.  Try doing this before creating the "`UIBarButtonItem`".

```
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f);
```

The last number is the height and the second to last number is the button width.

Comment: nopes. Its working fine as it was before, its just not visible

Comment: THat shows the rounded rect button with none of my formatting and UIButtonTypeCustom is still the same, working fine but nothing in place of left bar button

Comment: You may want to make certain that your custom font ("CrimeFighter BB") is actually on the iPhone or somewhere where the application can find & load it.